# Pandoc Conversion Failure With Knitr

Tags: r, knitr, r-markdown, kableextra, kable

I think my problem is straightforward enough that it can be answered without a MRE. Here's the code that's throwing an error:

```
DSP %>%
kable(format = "latex",
        digits = 2,
        booktabs = T,
        format.args = list(big.mark = ',')) %>%
  kable_styling(font_size = 9,latex_options = c("striped", "scale_down")) %>%
  column_spec(1, bold = TRUE) %>%
  column_spec(10, bold = TRUE) %>%
  row_spec(nrow(DSP), bold = T)
```

I'm running this in an RMarkdown file, which I execute in a FOR loop, with i = 50. In other words, the data frame DSP gets re-generated 50 times, and each time it has a different number of rows. DSP always has 10 columns.

I want to bold the last row.

For i = 1, nrows = 14. No problem. For i=2, nrows= 10. No problem. For i=3, nrows = 9. I get this:

```
/Applications/RStudio.app/Contents/MacOS/pandoc/pandoc +RTS -K512m -RTS statement_merge.utf8.md --to latex --from markdown+autolink_bare_uris+ascii_identifiers+tex_math_single_backslash-implicit_figures --output pandoc1246b13bd105f.pdf --template /Users/steve-guest/Library/R/3.4/library/rmarkdown/rmd/latex/default-1.17.0.2.tex --highlight-style tango --latex-engine pdflatex --variable graphics=yes --variable 'geometry:margin=1in' 
! Package array Error:  Illegal pream-token (N): `c' used.

See the array package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.123 \end{tabular}}

pandoc: Error producing PDF
Error: pandoc document conversion failed with error 43
In addition: Warning messages:
1: Removed 7 rows containing missing values (position_stack). 
2: Removed 33 rows containing missing values (position_stack). 
3: Removed 7 rows containing missing values (position_stack). 
4: Removed 22 rows containing missing values (position_stack). 
5: Removed 5 rows containing missing values (position_stack). 
6: Removed 8 rows containing missing values (position_stack).
```

If I then replace `nrow(DSP)` with the number 9 and call the `render()` statement, it still fails, but with a different error message:

```
output file: statement_merge.knit.md

/Applications/RStudio.app/Contents/MacOS/pandoc/pandoc +RTS -K512m -RTS statement_merge.utf8.md --to latex --from markdown+autolink_bare_uris+ascii_identifiers+tex_math_single_backslash-implicit_figures --output pandoc1246b295881e6.pdf --template /Users/steve-guest/Library/R/3.4/library/rmarkdown/rmd/latex/default-1.17.0.2.tex --highlight-style tango --latex-engine pdflatex --variable graphics=yes --variable 'geometry:margin=1in' 
! Package array Error:  Illegal pream-token (N): `c' used.

See the array package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.123 \end{tabular}}

pandoc: Error producing PDF
Error: pandoc document conversion failed with error 43
In addition: Warning messages:
1: Removed 5 rows containing missing values (position_stack). 
2: Removed 8 rows containing missing values (position_stack).
```

Does anyone know why this is happening? And even better, how I can fix it?

Thanks!

**EDIT: pandoc headers**

```
---
output: 
  pdf_document:
    fig_caption: false
header-includes:
  - \usepackage{booktabs}
  - \usepackage{longtable}
  - \usepackage{array}
  - \usepackage{multirow}
  - \usepackage[table]{xcolor}
  - \usepackage{wrapfig}
  - \usepackage{float}
  - \usepackage{colortbl}
  - \usepackage{pdflscape}
  - \usepackage{tabu}
  - \usepackage{threeparttable}

  - \definecolor{ufogrn}{rgb}{.2,.3,.1}

---
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it is a good practice to try to break down your pipeline and identify where the problem comes from.  I had the same issue, and in my case it came from 
`kableExtra::column_spec()` when I accidentally formatted a non-existing column.

When you get the error message from LaTex that is a sign that something went wrong in formatting, and it is not always very intuitive where. Your pipeline is starting from a data set, and via the `kable` and `kableExtra` functions in each step it add some latex markups to the data. If you identify which step causes the problem, you can usually find the cause easily.

Comment: Thanks Daniel. It took me a while, but I finally figured out the solution -- by doing what you recommended. (I wish I'd read your answer first!)